# Difference in harangue, tirade and rant?

Tags: word-choice, word-difference

What is the difference in usage between *harangue*, *tirade* and *rant*? I found these definitions by googling "define X" keyword:

- **Harangue**: a lengthy and aggressive speech.
- **Tirade**: a long, angry speech of criticism or accusation.
- **Rant**: speak or shout at length in an angry, impassioned way.

In which situations is a specific word better to use than the others? What is the difference between them?

Comment: I'd say tirade & rant are almost interchangeable. Rant is less formal. Harangue, on the other hand, is normally directed *at* someone specific; right in their face.

Comment: See also: diatribe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Harangue and rant can be used as either a noun or a verb, but tirade can only be used as a noun.

Harangue as a noun is a lengthy and aggressive speech given to an audience of some sort. Harangue as a verb is lengthy and aggressive speech directed at someone or some group in particular.

Rant as a noun is interchangeable with tirade. Rant as a verb is somewhat different than harangue because it isn't directed at anyone. When you rant, you're making a lengthy, angry speech to anyone within earshot. Tirade and rant can be used to describe angry writing, and I associate harangue with angry speech only (AmE).

A tirade can only be a noun, and is more commonly used than harangue. It is very close to both a rant and a harangue, but it doesn't have the sense of being addressed to an audience like a harangue does, nor the sense of not being directed to any particular audience that rant does.

> *Whenever she watched cable news, she would rant about the lack of standards in modern journalism. These rants could last for an hour.*
>
> *Whenever she watched cable news, her tirade on the lack of standards in modern journalism would last for an hour.*
>
> *Whenever she watched cable news, she would harangue us about the lack of standards in modern journalism. The only way to end her harangue was to turn off the TV.*

Comment: @Ooker I'm glad you found my answer helpful, but I would wait a little while before accepting an answer. There is a good post explaining why on the meta site: http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1307/9161

Comment: Does *tirade* simply not imply the target of the audience, and you can use it whenever there are a person to listen or not?

Comment: @Ooker You can use tirade anywhere you can use rant as a noun. The difference between them is almost too small to mention in my experience. Harangue is the only one of the three words that I think has a unique connotation.