# Can "Tirade" be used for a *non-angry* lengthy, boring speech/text?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, word-request

When looking for a word for a lengthy, tedious, boring, text*, I had the feeling that *tirade* could be the right one.

However I looked it up in on-line dictionaries and all of the the ones I consulted say that it's supposed to refer to an **angry** speech/text.

I'm not yet convinced though, I think I heard it used for what I'm looking for, in a humorous manner (and maybe the dictionaries I looked up only reported the canonical meaning).

So, can you native speakers confirm, or confute, my impression?

* I have already, unsatisfactorily, read [Idiom to describe a text (or speech) which is too long](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/100813/idiom-to-describe-a-text-or-speech-which-is-too-long).

Comment: Related question: [Difference between tirade, harangue, and rant](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/48696/difference-in-harangue-tirade-and-rant)

Answer (score 8):

If you want a word that is *non-angry*, long, and boring, then *tirade* is not it. The dictionaries aren't wrong. A tirade is given in anger.

Perhaps you're thinking of the third sense of Merriam-Webster's definition of [**monologue**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/monologue):

> **3** : a long speech monopolizing conversation
>   // I stifled a yawn as she continued her *monologue* about her vacation experiences.

This has the advantage of being applicable to both speech and text.

---

Or, there's the verb [**drone**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/drone#h2):

> **b** : to talk in a persistently dull or monotonous tone
>   // *droning* on and on about his health

However, this one is applicable only to speech.

Answer (score 8):

If you are talking about a written document, a somewhat obscure term is *screed*:

> **[screed](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/screed)** (n): a long piece of writing, especially one that is boring or expresses an unreasonably strong opinion:

A recent example of its use:

> Brown joined the company in 2017, not long before a **screed** against Google’s diversity efforts written by engineer James Damore went viral.

If not actually *angry*, a "tirade" should be at least *loud* and *energetic* and usually refers to *oratory*.  If the speech was long but dull I would instead use something like *monologue*, or say the speaker *droned on* for some length of time.  It can be boring (or at least tedious and repetitive), but since that's not included in the definition, you'd have to explicitly add that information.

> I managed to get through the text of her speech, which was mostly an **interminable** tirade against the evils of *gluten*.

A "harangue" is similarly energetic, and usually is meant to make the listener feel *guilty* for some misdeed.  As with "tirade", if it's boring, you'd have to say so.

> After we got home, covered in filth, our father launched a **tedious harangue** at us about how foolish we were to play around the storm drains after a heavy rain.  As if we didn't already know.

Comment: Screed is absolutely spot on: conveys exactly the right degree of self-righteous tedium.

Comment: Screed does look like a suitable word but it's a very obscure word that few people will have heard of.

Comment: @user5505  Yes, I agree.  It might have most native English speakers scratching their heads, but still most could pick up the meaning from context.  I've added a recent example from an article in *Wired*.

Answer (score 6):

Tirade strongly suggests a long loud speach full of angry or unbalanced criticisms and complaints.

In contrast a harangue suggests a long tedious and pushy persuasive speach, but not necessarily an openly angry speaker.

Comment: Really? So harangue could be a good solution?

Comment: Although it's the first word I thought of, too, _harangue_ might be [too emotive](https://wikidiff.com/tirade/harangue) for "boring" and "tedious".

Comment: harangue is usually directed at a particular person. "He was haranguing me." Tirade is just "put out there". It's what the current U.S. president does.  It could be to a bunch of people or only one. But  meaning is basically the same: angry and off-the-cuff and somewhat disjointed.

Comment: @Lambie The original meaning of "harangue" is a "a speech addressed to a public assembly" (Webster's Ninth New Collegiate Dictionary). Later meanings given include "a bombastic ranting speech or writing".

Comment: @David42 Yes,well, if you harangue your audience, the audience is like a unit.

Answer (score 2):

A lengthy, tedious, and boring text lacks the energy to catalyse any excitement and I would always associate a **tirade** with a long angry provocative speech whether oral or written.  The closest synonym would be a rant which seems to me interchangeable as a less "fancy" word choice.

The word **tome** *(for a text only)* is more appropriate for the length and tedium but isn't nearly cruel enough if you are using the word as a weapon. If you are doing a review of the tome I would recommend launching into a tirade given what you have just been subjected to for hours on end :-)